# Storing Large Number of Graph Data Structures in a Database

Tags: mysql, database, computer-science, graph-theory, large-data-volumes

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564673/does-it-make-sense-to-map-a-graph-data-structure-into-a-relational-database) asks about storing a single graph in a relational database. The solution is clear in that case: one table for nodes, one table for edges.

I have a graph data structure that evolves over time, so I would like to store "snapshots" of this graph in a database. I imagine having hundreds of such snapshots.

One solution is to create a whole new table pair of nodes and edges (as above) for **each** snapshot. Is there a better solution?

EDIT: It was asked what I would like to do with this database. I believe that I will not be doing any querying except to dump **all** of the graphs to MySQL from C++ and then load it **all** back into C++ data structures. So I'm looking to use MySQL for storage and not for efficient random access / searching.

Comment: Could you add some detail about what you'd like to be able to do with your historical graphs?  Will you need to be able to run queries/searches against them?

Comment: I believe that I will not be doing any querying except to dump all of the graphs to MySQL from C++ and then load it all back into C++ data structures. So I'm looking to use MySQL for storage and not for efficient random access / searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a table

```
 graphs = (graphid, dateofsnapshot or other things unique to the snapshot)
```

and you need the nodes and edges tables but with a foriegn key reference to the graphs table. This way you can have an arbitrary number of graphs in the database.

Comment: Do you think is more efficient for the task described in the EDIT than  creating a new table for each graph?

Comment: @Lex Fridman I still think that a properly normalized design is better than creating a new pair of tables per graph.